# Purpose of building file using Make

Tags: c++, builds, cmake

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of making files using commands such as `cmake ..` and `make`, I have tried looking online but there is no concise explanation on its purpose that i could find.

Also, is it necessary to use `make` on a project folder that is not built in order to use the source (C++) in other projects.

I know this may be a simplistic question, but as i am fairly new to building files, any information or references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your program consists of a only a few files that can be built with a simple command line invoking the compiler, then `make` may be superfluous. However, in large projects you may have dozens of files that require complex compiler and linker options, then `make` or a similar tool becomes a necessity. Consider, if you have a project with 50 C++ source files, and you change just one of them, you don't want to have re-compile all of them. You'd much rather  just re-compile the one file that changed and re-link with the existing object files for the rest of them. Tools like `make` automatically take care of chores like that.

The `make` language has a number of warts, and I don't think it is anybody's favorite programming language. It is also very tricky to write a `makefile` that will work on multiple platforms, say Linux, OS X, and Windows. Tools like `cmake` can be used to generate `makefiles` that will work on multiple platforms, and lets you describe the process of building your software in a language that is arguably less ugly than `make` proper.

Comment: `make` language is in fact one of my favorite languages.

Comment: Hmm. Well, de gustibus non est disputandum. I think you'll have  to admit that you are in a minority on that.

Comment: I was not even aware that it is a language of its own! very helpful , thankyou. Will upvote when i can.

Answer (score 5):

`make` is sort of a batch process for compiling/linking/building, etc.  You could do all of these steps manually, or you can just use `make`.

More info here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html and http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Answer (score 2):

Until your project is small, it is very easy to build it without any makefiles. But imagine your projects has 200 source files that you've divided in to a number of static and dynamic libraries, then passing the names of 200 files to the compiler in a command prompt would be impossible. Also you can create a batch file which builds your projects. But make files are superior to batch files. Particularly, when you use `cmake` your source code can be built with any compiler easily. That is why large projects use makefiles.

Note: If you use any convinient IDE like Visual Studio, you'll not often feel the need of writing makefiles, as the IDE makes it easy for you.

Comment: Elaborate answer thanks. Is it then possible to build the file directly from an IDE like Visual Studio?

Comment: No, you can't build a makefile using an IDE. But some large projects include projects files for such IDE. Open it and click the build option. In fact, some of the IDEs like CodeLite create a makefile automatically. In some of them you can turn on the feature.